# How to capture video stream from Android phone screen and show it on laptop?

Tags: android

How to capture video stream from Android phone screen and show it on laptop? I've got Android 2.2 device.

I need this to show how my application work on the conference in real time. Something like IPhone presentation on Mac World.

Comment: This is quite an involved thing to do, and I'm sure no one is going to post all of the code for you. I suggest you do a little more research and ask a better, more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best tool I found: http://www.mightypocket.com/2010/08/android-screenshots-screen-capture-screen-cast/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post can help you out. [Present your application on a DataShow](http://www.necronet.info/2011/08/present-your-android-application-on.html)

Gives you two alternative one is MightyPocket and the other one is androidscreencast project.